# RequiredFieldValidater to textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net

I am building a social network on asp.net c#,

So my textbox need a RequiredFieldValidater [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ututp.jpg)

could someboday tell me how to add this Please fill out this field validater to textboxes on my website, 
Now i am using this code,

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="Your_Name" ErrorMessage="Enter Your Name" 
                        ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="RegisterGroup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: i think its HTML5 `Required` Attribute

Comment: Cannot we do it on asp.net c#???

Comment: Are you using Webforms or MVC? In MVC you can't use RequiredFieldValidator because it's a Webform control

Comment: no no  i am not using mvc,

Comment: @SupunMadhushankaGunarathna See my updated ans !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **required attribute with your server control** not with validation control

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
        Your name:<br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtName" required="required"/>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="RequiredFieldValidator1" controltovalidate="Your_Name" ForeColor="Red" errormessage="Please enter your name!" />
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnSubmitForm" text="Ok" onclick="btnSubmitForm_Click" />
    </form>
```

In the CodeBehind file event handler:

```
protected void btnSubmitForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Page.IsValid)
    {
        btnSubmitForm.Text = "My form is valid!";
    }
}
```

Comment: but little error, I want to display this when register button press only, but when my page has 2 button and i click another button which is  not relevant to this ,this message will pop up, what can i do for it? i meant this message pop up for all buttons